# PWA installed or not?

Tags: web, device, progressive-web-apps

I wanted to know is there a way by which we can check whether our website's PWA is installed or not by the user on the device?
I have done with the " add to home screen banner" but what if the user comes the second time and we need to check. Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/getinstalledrelatedapps#detect_if_your_pwa_is_installed_from_a_native_app). Be noted that if the user has installed your Progressive Web App through the old Add to Homescreen method (i.e, in anything prior to Chrome 58) then it is not possible to detect if your app is installed. Chrome added your site to the Homescreen as a bookmark, and this data was not exposed to the system.

However, if the user has installed the web app using the new Web APK functionality, it is possible to determine if your web app is installed. If you know the package name of your Web APK then you can use the `context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo()` API to determine if it is installed. Please note that this is experimental.

Comment: Question, since Chrome generates the WebAPK on `Add to Homescreen`, how would you access the `getPackageManager()` API? i.e. how would you access any other API's than those exposed through the navigator?

Ref:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/android/webapk/shell_apk/src/org/chromium/webapk